# How to delete text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so my code takes the input value of `"textmoney"` and shows how much money you make a year. When you press enter a button will pop up that will show you the advances statistics of the number that you entered in "textmoney". Basically, i can't get the statistics text to disappear when there is nothing in the text bar `"textmoney"`. It does it with displaying the main number and the stats button, but not the actual data. The stats data is the 
$secondp, $minutep, and so on. What am i doing wrong? I said in the statFunction tag that if the value of `"textmoney" == 0`, then it should hide all the stats data.

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $demo = $('#demo');
var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');
var $stat = $('#stat');


var $secondp = $('#second');
var $minutep = $('#minute');
var $hourp = $('#hour');
var $dayp = $('#day');
var $weekp = $('#week');
var $monthp = $('#month');
var $yearp = $('#year');

$('#stat').hide();

function getmoney(){
     var money = $textMoney.val();
        if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
            $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
        } else {
            var dailyE = $textMoney.val() * 365;
            $demo.text('$' + (dailyE - 1150) + " - " + "$" + (dailyE + 1254) + ' per year');
        }
}

function statFunction() {

    var dailyE = $textMoney.val() * 365;
    var $second = (dailyE / 365) /24 /60 /60
    var $minute = (dailyE / 365) /24 /60;
    var $hour = (dailyE / 365) / 24;
    var $day = dailyE / 365;
    var $week = dailyE / 52;
    var $month = dailyE / 12;
    var $year = dailyE;
    $secondp.text("$" + $second + "      a second");
    $minutep.text("$" + $minute + "      a minute");
    $hourp.text("$" + $hour + "      an hour");
    $dayp.text("$" + ($day - 52) + " - " + "$" + ($day + 53) + " " + "   a day");
    $weekp.text("$" + $week + "      a week");
    $monthp.text("$" + $month + "      a month");
    $yearp.text("$" + ($year - 1150) + " - " + "$" + ($year + 1254) + " per year");

    var money = $textMoney.val();
        if (money == 0) {
            $secondp.hide();
        }   

}

// on enter key
$textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        getmoney();
        $('#stat').show();
    } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $demo.text('');
        $('#stat').hide();
    }
}).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
});

// on click 
$moneydiv.click(function(){    
    getmoney();
    $('#stat').show();
});

$stat.click(function() {
    statFunction();
 })

});
</script>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Feel free to add a working code snippet of your combined HTML and JavaScript using Ctrl+M

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your keydown function.

You want to say something like this:

```
// on enter key
$textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        getmoney(); // call this function
        if ( $textMoney.val() == '') { // if $textMoney is empty then hide stats
            $('#stat').hide();
        } else { // otherwise show stats
            $('#stat').show();
        }
    }
});
```

I would say though, that there are probably some other ways that you could clean up your code, but that should solve your problem for now.